# Invalid hook call in next-auth

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, graphql, next-auth

I am using next-auth in my next app, using https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen graphql code-generator to generate my login mutation. When i use this loginMutation (which is simlar to useMutation), I get error while logging in:

`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:\n1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)\n2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks\n3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app\nSee https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.`

Below is my config in [...nextauth].ts

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { useLoginUserMutation } from 'src/generated/graphql'

export const nextAuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/pages/login'
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { username, password } = credentials as { username: string; password: string }
        // Add credentials verify logic here
        const [loginUserMutation, { data: user, loading, error }] = useLoginUserMutation()
        await loginUserMutation({
          variables: {
            username: username,
            password: password
          }
        })

        if (user) {
          return user
        } else {
          return null
        }
      }
    })
  ]
} as NextAuthOptions

export default NextAuth(nextAuthOptions)
```

Comment: you can use hooks only inside react components

Comment: I understood that by reading the error ofcourse, any way I can call hook from authorize function of CredentialsProvider?

Comment: no. hooks mean hooking into react lifecycle in functional components